# Jquery плагин с proto

Tags: jquery, prototype

Здравствуйте, подскажите, что я делаю не так http://jsfiddle.net/2bSGM/2/. 
Почему не выполняется метод this.init()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в том контексте this - это jq-коллекция dom-объектов.

Comment: Как это исправить, не подскажите?

Comment: Исправить что? Это не ошибка, а стандартное поведение. Представьте, что где-то в глубине притаилось что-то вроде $.fn.qqq.apply(COLLECTION, arguments);

Comment: @rimlin, почитайте эту статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/158235/

Comment: @likerRr, спасибо, разобрался.